# SMTP Auth - SASL on Dovecot, Postfix and CentOS 6.2 (and Open-Xchange)

Tags: authentication, postfix, ssl, smtp, imap

I am trying to get open SASL to work on CentOS 6.2. I followed this tutorial:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_sasl

I suspect it works perfectly for CentOS 5.x so all I really need is an update for use on CentOS 6.2. I was feeling confident right up until I discovered half way through that dovecot.conf goes mad with these settings.

This link recommends that people running CentOS 6 use a different method.

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL

Neither of the methods outlined in these links work.

Also I don't know how to get Open-Xchange to use SMTP authentication. It seems to be very poorly documented and their CE forum is not letting me post, nor is it showing much activity at all.

Comment: I can help you using tls.The example of main.cf in postfix below here : smtpd_use_tls = yes \
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/public_sl7.pem \
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/private_sl7.pem \
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache  \ I used it on Scientific Linux 7.2

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is there but you need a lot of google foo to find it and some experience with Dovecot and Postfix to make the connections.

1. Configure Dovecot with and authentication backend of your choice
2. configure Postfix to use Dovecot SASL mechanism as provided in you link
3. Install open-xchange-authentication-imap as SASL backend is on Dovecot not Postfix: http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Authentication_IMAP_Plugin_description
4. Install open-xhange-changepw-script and configure changing of passwords in Dovecot from the OX frontend: http://oxpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=ChangePasswordExternal#Enable_the_password_change_dialog_within_the_AppSuite_Frontend
5. Create users with context as domain.tld as suggested in previous link, when creating users in ox via the command also create the same user in dovecot with same username and password

That's it